# invalid query string parameters OK to throw error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, custom-errors

What is the best way to handle an error that I believe a bot is appending bad information to a URL? Example: https://www.example.org/notes.aspx?id=15032386122&pn=15032386121'A=0

Currently the errors are being sent to an inbox, the page is using the value and throwing an "Input string was not in a correct format.". This is filling up the error inbox with useless emails.

I could check for invalid values and throw a new error type. Then based on the type determine if I should send an email. That seems frivolous and adds extra complexity.

Comment: Why not fixing the error first? Usually that kind of exception could be avoided with proper checking the inputs

Comment: Validate the field? There isn't a clear way to do that without specifying exactly to remove the substring 'A=0. If I remove anything but a number I would be left with that 0 still.